# Lower timeout for Node.js socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I want to verify using Node.js whether a certain port is reachable or not. Basically, what I did is write the following program:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(3003, 'localhost');

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit();
});

client.once('connect', function () {
  console.log('Connected!');
  process.exit();
});
```

So far, this pretty much works fine. There is only one thing I'm not happy with, and that is the timeout handling. Locally it works as expected, but when I try

```
client.connect(81, 'www.google.de');
```

it takes up to two minutes until I get a timeout. Why is that happening, and what can I do against it?

PS: I know that there is the [setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) function for sockets in Node.js, but either it does not what I think it should, or I am using it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this lines for handle timeout:

```
client.setTimeout(1000);
client.on('timeout', function(){
  client.end();
})'
```

or:

```
client.setTimeout(1000, function(){
  client.end();
});
```

Docs: [here](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback)

Comment: Ahhhh, there's a `timeout` event! Thanks so much! Sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees :-)

Comment: You can also add `timeout` listener as a second argument of `setTimeout` ;)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful :-)